# Importing numpy using IronPython in C#

Tags: c#, python, numpy, ironpython, python.net

I am trying to use numpy module functions in my Python code that i run inside my c# application in VS13.

I'm doing this to import the module:

```
ScriptEngine pyEngine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope pyScope = pyEngine.CreateScope();

pyEngine.Execute("import numpy", pyScope);
```

however it says "No module named numpy".
I was looking for the solution and found this:
[How to install numpy and scipy for Ironpython27? Old method doens't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397540/how-to-install-numpy-and-scipy-for-ironpython27-old-method-doenst-work)
Using Nilsters answer I managed to install numpy and im able to use it when i run ipy from cmd. However i dont know how to use it in my c# app in VS.
I've been looking through the files and found

\IronPython 2.7\DLLs\NumpyDotNet.dll

and also:

\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\numpy\

How do i make it possible for my python code to import numpy?

Comment: you can use pythonnet for this.

Comment: Where can i find detailed information about Python.Net and instructions on how to use it in my c# application. I try to reference Python.Reference.dll like this site suggests http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html. But cant call PythonEngine.Intialize().

Comment: if you already have CPython installed then try `pip install pythonnet`, otherwise WinPython comes with pythonnet bundled in it: https://winpython.github.io/

Comment: you can also build the latest from source: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

Comment: here is a simple instruction on how to use pythonnet from C#: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I managed to install PythonNet already. I'm  wondering if just referencing Python.Runtime.dll in my project is enough. Also when i run the code u sent me i get an error on this line    dynamic b = np.array(new List<float> { 6, 5, 4 }, Py.kw("dtype", np.int32));      TypeError : long() argument must be a string or a number, not '0. However the most important thing i need to do is to be able to just run my python script in my app and pass args to it. Could you please give an example on that?

Comment: There is an open issue about `dynamic b = np.array(new List<float> { 6, 5, 4 }, Py.kw("dtype", np.int32))`: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/249

Comment: You do not need pythonnet to just run python scripts with args passed. Pythonnet is used for embedding and extending CPython.