# How to install NumPy for IronPython in 2017?

Tags: python, .net, numpy, ironpython, python.net

I have found the old answer to this question, but the instructions provided in the mentioned post are no longer working... Essentially the URL where NumPy for IronPython was stored is broken.

[How to install NumPy for IronPython in 2015/2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397540/how-to-install-numpy-and-scipy-for-ironpython27-old-method-doenst-work)

Comment: Nope. I did not find a solution unfortunetelly. I am planning to switch my project to python.NET in order to enable NumPy support. I recommend to you doing same.

Comment: Updated Instructions July 2019: [How to install numpy and scipy for Ironpython27?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397540)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install numpy and scipy for Ironpython27?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397540/how-to-install-numpy-and-scipy-for-ironpython27). These are fundamentally the same question, as the back-and-forth posting of updated answers shows.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the required wheel file from https://pypi.org/project/numpy.

Update the pip to the latest version based on your OS.

*If you are unable to use pip, please add pip to your PATH by editing
environment variables.*

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

After upgrading pip, you can use pip to install the local *.whl file you downloaded

```
pip install C:\path\to\whl_file.whl
```

For more customized install, you can look here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 1):

Paste this in to your terminal

```
pip install numpy
```

If it say: `pip is not recognized as an internal or external command`, then try reinstalling Python and remember to add it to PATH (Easiest step. There is more ways to fix this but
this is the easiest one).

Then, it will work perfectly :)