# Inline initialization of two-dimensional typed array in IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython

I have a question about typed array initialization in IronPython. I want to initialize inline typed two-dimensional array in IronPython.
In IronPython I discovered how to initialize simple typed array:

```
pythonTypedArray = Array[int]([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and how to initialize typed array of arrays:

```
pythonTypedArrayOfArrays = Array[Array[int]]([Array[int]([0, 1]), Array[int]([2, 3])])
```

For example, in C# I can do like so:

```
int[,] twoDimensionalArray = new int[,] { {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9} };
```

Can I initialize inline two-dimensional typed array in IronPython? If no, what is the best way to initialize two-dimensional typed array in IronPython?

Comment: use `numpy` http://www.numpy.org/

Comment: Are you sure this is Python ? It doesn't look like it is...

Comment: I'm sorry for not mentioning this. This question is related to IronPython where I can use .NET types.

Comment: @Bill: please [edit] your question.

Comment: @Bill You should tag it as such.

Comment: @WillemVanOssem Done.

Answer (score 2):

So, you need a matrix. In Python it can be achieved by doing this:

```
matrix = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
```

Or using [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html) (you can install it by running `pip install numpy`):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.zeros((4, 4))
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

In numpy, generating a matrix with random numbers is as simple as:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.rand(2,3)
array([[ 0.22568268,  0.0053246 ,  0.41282024],
       [ 0.68824936,  0.68086462,  0.6854153 ]])
```

IMO, whenever you want matrices, you want to use `numpy` because it has some nice methods which really help you process them.

---

//EDIT: Since you added more context, in IronPython you can create an array of arrays by doing:

```
array = Array[Array[int]]( ( (1,2), (3,4) ) )
```

or you can create multidimensional arrays is to use `Array.CreateInstance` passing type as a first argument followed by dimension sizes:

```
array = Array.CreateInstance(int, 2, 3)
```

You can always read [the docs](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php?title=Typed_Arrays_in_IronPython) when you need more information

Comment: Where did numpy come from?

Comment: Added some references for it ;P

Comment: @MrGrj if I Use Array.CreateInstance method, then how can I fill this array with values?

Comment: Yes. And there is only that way?

Comment: @MrGrj, what about inline initialization for `array = Array.CreateInstance(int, 2, 3)` variant?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy
a = numpy.arange(12)
a.shape = 3,  4
print(a)
>>>
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
```

Comment: Could you provide any information on how can I install numpy? I've tried instructions from this link, but it does not work(Could not download ironpkg-1.0.0.py file): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397540/how-to-install-numpy-and-scipy-for-ironpython27-old-method-doenst-work

Comment: It's Tricky. Use scientific python instead. like Anaconda, WinPython, Just google it. They have numpy and the like pre-installed.